# jquery autocomplete no work if generate from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

Autocomplete it's working perfectly, as expected if using a normal statics html/php page.

But I'm working on a module that loads dynamically (AJAX) generate same HTML as above into a  area. I cannot get the autocomplete to work.

Any idea of how can I solve this? I've searched everywhere and tried everything, but obviously not the right solution yet.

```
//
// this is the ajax code load dynamic contents in a #display_area
// from onclick=selected_purchase()
//

    function selected_purchase() {
      var fields = $(":input").serialize();
        $.ajax({ 
        url: "purchase4",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: fields ,
        beforesend: function(a) {
            // before send process here
            showBusy();
        },
        success: function(html) {
            // success process here ...
            processForm(html);

        }   
    });

      }


//
// this is the autocomplete code  
//

$( "#supplier" ).autocomplete({ //the recipient text field with id #supplier
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "search_supplier",
                dataType: "json",
                data: request,
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.response == 'true') {
                       response(data.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            // Do something extra on select...
                // add user id to hidden input    

            $('input[name="name"]').val(ui.item.value);
            $('input[name="sl"]').val(ui.item.sl_id);
            return false;
        },

    });
```

Comment: Kind of hard to help without seeing your code, could you post what you have so far?

Comment: thanks, added some code hope can help

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to initialize the plugin instance after the content has been loaded.

```
$("#container").load('some url', function() {
    $(this).find('#autocomplete').autocomplete();
});
```

This code might differ a bit depending on the method you use for loading the content ($.ajax, .load()...). The common thing is to initialize your plugin in the callback executed after the asynchronous request has finished, usually called the "success" callback.

---

Now we have your code samples, here's what you should do:

```
function selected_purchase() {
    var fields = $(":input").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(html) {
            // success process here ...
            processForm(html);

            // assuming "processForm" append the "html" to the DOM
            // you can now call autocomplete
            $( "#supplier" ).autocomplete({
                ...
            });
        }
    });
}​
```

Comment: If processForm() is the method that appends your new html, then yes.

Comment: @DidierGhys I have implemented as per your suggetion ... $("#PaymentIn").load('/Bank/_PaymentIn/', function () {
                    $(this).find('#ChequeNo').autocomplete();
                    });

     $("input#ChequeNo").autocomplete({......but this does not work...any idea plz..

Comment: @Sadaquat I cannot help you with a "does not work". Do you get errors in the console ? Have you tried debugging inside the callback to check if you can find the elements you're trying to use ? Is the data correctly loaded ?

Comment: @DidierGhys Thanks your solution worked but with some different syntax, the reason is same as you have said but I had rapped an  autocomplete in a function so I just called that function after an ajax and it worked like a charm...:)Thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

Your Php script (I guess) is sending JSon ? That's the usual problem, your outstream should look like

```
['toto','titi','tata']
```

You could use `echo json_encode($myArrayWithStringValues)` for the same result.